# Is there a way to get metrics from Cloud Run Jobs, like memory and CPU usage, the same way we have for Cloud Run Services?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I would like to get the memory and CPU usage og the Cloud Run Jobs

Answer (score 2):

As of the moment, the feature you were looking for is under feature request and no ETA on when it will be launched.

Comment: Dion, do you have a link?